# C# can't make http request from website or service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to write a simple POST request to google-analytics server, here is my code :

```
        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {


            var values = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            //values["v"] = "1";
            //values["t"] = "event";
            //values["tid"] = trackingID;
            //values["cid"] = clientID;
            //values["ec"] = eventCategory.ToString();
            //values["ea"] = eventAction.ToString();
            //values["el"] = eventAction.ToString();

            var endpointAddress = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect";
            var response = client.UploadValues(endpointAddress, values);

            var responseString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        }
```

This code works fine in a console application, but not on a website application (hosted on IIS or run on Visual Studio 2013) or in a WCF (likewise).
I checked using

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

in both the site, the WCF service and the application, everytime the DOMAIN and USERNAME are my own, so I don't think that is the problem. I have tried using .NET impersonation without success.

I've tried setting the application pool identity to my user, ApplicationPoolIdentity or NetworkService, without success.
I've also tried changing the authentication mode to AnonymousUser or Windows Authentication. I've tried changing the physical access path, without success.
I'm at work behind a proxy, at home I've tried it and it worked well.

Does anyone has an idea as to why it doesn't work ?

Comment: So are you getting and error?

Comment: @DavidMasters Yes, I get the following error :

    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: OK. FYI - Error messages are quite useful to put into your question =)

Comment: So, same code is ok when you run it at home BUT at works fails?  Have you tried supplying the proxy credentials?

Comment: Have you tried running any network analysis software to see what is getting sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try supplying the proxy details when making the request.  Assuming you are behind a proxy.

```
    using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("localproxyIP:8080", true);
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("domain\\user", "password");
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
        client.Proxy = proxy;

        var values = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        //values["v"] = "1";
        //values["t"] = "event";
        //values["tid"] = trackingID;
        //values["cid"] = clientID;
        //values["ec"] = eventCategory.ToString();
        //values["ea"] = eventAction.ToString();
        //values["el"] = eventAction.ToString();

        var endpointAddress = "http://www.google-analytics.com/collect";
        var response = client.UploadValues(endpointAddress, values);

        var responseString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    }
```

Comment: Ok this worked ! I had to dig into the proxy.pac script but it worked anyway, thanks a lot